# $_GET does not work in some areas of the page

Tags: php, variables, get, constants

So my page has a lot of include calls on different parts of the page.  Most of these includes have some kind of function that grabs any $_GET variables.  All of them work fine, except my navigation file which doesn't return anything when I try to grab any GET variables.

nav.php

```
<? require_once("config.php"); require_once("functions.php"); ?>

<div id="nav">

    <ul>

        <? initializeMainNav( $_GET['page'] ); ?>

    </ul>

</div>
```

inside function.php

```
function initializeMainNav( $curPage )
{

    // array ( slug, name ) of navigation items

    $nav = array(
        array( "", "Home" ),
        array( "case_studies", "Investment Case Studies" ),
        array( "current_inv", "Current Investments" ),
        array( "about", "About MDIG" ),
        array( "management", "Management" ),
        array( "news", "News" ),
        array( "services", "Services" ) );

    // Print out each nav item, and highlight the current page nav item

    for( $i = 0; $i < count( $nav ); $i++ ) {

        echo "  <li><a ";

        if( $nav[$i][0] == $curPage )
            echo "class=\"active\" ";

        echo "  href=\"?page=" . $nav[$i][0] . "\">" . $nav[$i][1] . "</a></li> ";

    }

}
```

$_GET['page'] always returns empty, even tho it works on all other parts of the page.  You guys see something I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:

index.php where `HEADER` is a constant var that defines a path, located in `config.php`

```
<? require_once("config.php"); require_once("functions.php"); ?>


<? include(HEADER); ?>

<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="logo"> 
            <a href="<? echo DOMAIN; ?>"><img src="<? echo IMAGES; ?>/logo.png" alt="<? echo COMPANY; ?>"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>


        <? include(NAV); ?>


        <div id="content_wrapper">

            <!-- Find and display appropriate page -->
            <? displayPage( $_GET['page'] ); ?>

        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>


        <? include(FOOTER); ?>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If your `$_GET['page']` is empty, i think there is a problem when you pass this var to the script.

Comment: @MarcioSimao is right. your code works for me when I pass "page" as a GET parameter.

Comment: I realize you can pass in a variable, but my issue is that $_GET['page'] does not return anything.  It works on different included php files on the same page, so i just dont get why its not working specifically for this file

Comment: Why count a array you already know the size..?

Comment: So are you saying that your nav echos out correctly, except that "Home" is always active?

Comment: @Gabriel : Because I'm making this for somebody else, who may add/remove menu items.

Comment: @Iain Fraser : Yes exactly, and when i try to view $_GET['page'] either in the function or directly on the nav.php page it doesn't hold any value, even tho other pages are able to access it fine

Comment: Very strange. Can you show us an example of where nav.php gets included in a page?

Comment: @IainFraser Ok I updated it with my `index.php`

Comment: oh lord I figured it out, I replaced the `include(NAV)` with `include("nav.php")` and it works now.  Does using constants interfere with certain things such as `GET` variables?

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't necessarily give you the answer as to why it isn't working, but how about something like the following:

functions.php

```
function echoMainNav($curPage)
{
   echo '<div id="nav"><ul>';
   echo initializeMainNav( $curPage );
   echo '</ul></div>';
}
```

somepage.php

```
<? require_once("config.php"); require_once("functions.php"); ?>


<? include(HEADER); ?>

<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="logo"> 
            <a href="<? echo DOMAIN; ?>"><img src="<? echo IMAGES; ?>/logo.png" alt="<? echo COMPANY; ?>"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>


        <? echoMainNav( $_GET['page'] ); ?>


        <div id="content_wrapper">

            <!-- Find and display appropriate page -->
            <? displayPage( $_GET['page'] ); ?>

        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>


        <? include(FOOTER); ?>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Or better yet:

templates.php

```
define('TEMPLATES_MAIN_NAV', '<div id="nav"><ul>%s</ul></div>');
```

functions.php

```
function getMainNav($curPage)
{
   return sprintf(TEMPLATES_MAIN_NAV, initializeMainNav( $curPage ) );
}
```

somepage.php

```
<?= getMainNav($_GET['page']); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Iain for all the help.  I actually solved the issue as I replaced the `include(NAV);` with `include("nav.php");` and it works now.  SO basically changed the constant to an actual string and it now allows me to use `GET` variables in `nav.php`

But I have been wondering how most people setup their templates.  I can't ever find good articles on clean template structures